# Rails - jQuery UI Dialog for a Form?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, modal-dialog

I have an 'items' controller and a 'new' method for creating different types of items.   I'd like to have that form in a jQuery UI Dialog window.  I started playing around tonight and was able to get a dialog to appear with with the form:

```
$("#load_form")
  .load('/items/new', {item_type: '#item_type_select'})
  .dialog({modal:true, width:'auto', height:'auto'});
```

Right now the form is strickly HTTP (form_for). When the form in the UI Dialog window is submitted (or really if any link is clicked or any page request), the UI Dialog window closes and the new page is loaded in the browser.

If it's possible for the jQuery UI Dialog window to 'change pages' and display the show page (form submit success) or the 'new' page again with fieldErrors (save fail),  what should I be looking at doing?  I'm not having any luck finding anything like a tutorial on how to setup a Rails form and the responses (save fail/success) for it a jQuery UI Dialog.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to submit the form using jQuery and handle the result on success as well with jQuery.

In order to submit a form with jQuery you could do something like this:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: this.method,
    url: this.action,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: "html",
    success: successHandler,
    error: errorHandler
  });
  return false;
});
```

`successHandler` and `errorHandler` are functions which will be invoked once the AJAX request has been completed, which one depends on the status code your server returns.

jQuery will then pass three parameters — `data, textStatus, jqXHR` for `success` and `jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown` for `error`. Since jQuery 1.5.1 you can also chain the callbacks or you can bind AJAX events to your container — for all options and more details check the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

In any case and depending on how you handle errors on the server, the callbacks will the place to insert the result back into your DOM, show/repopulate a modal etc..

You could e.g. simply replace the content of your modal or the form contained with the result the server sends back using `.html(data)`, parse errors etc.. Or you close the current modal and open a new one containing the data returned.